# Why does this rewrite rule result in an infinite loop?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to serve files matching a certain pattern from a subdirectory but my rule results in infinite redirect loop.  In this example I want to serve google site verification files from a new path:

```
RewriteRule ^(google.*html)$ /google_site_verification/$1 [L]
```

According to my error log this results in an internal redirect loop which keeps adding `/google_site_verification` to the path.  I have also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/google.*html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /google_site_verification/$1 [L]
```

Which gives the same result.  Since my regex explicitly defines beginning and ending of the pattern, why does `/google_site_verification/googleabcd1234.html` match?  The only thing I've tried that works is adding

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

into the chain, but I don't want to rely on the file not existing for things to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^(google[^/]*\.html)$ /google_site_verification/$1 [L]
```

Your problem is that both urls match:

/**google**.**html**
/**google**_site_verification/google.**html**

Comment: duh.. yeah I see now - it's matching the parent directory. which also contains the word google.